# network-output buffering using qdiscs in kernel

Tags: linux, networking, kernel, qemu

I have to implement a buffering and releasing of network output packets. My goal is to implement something which can buffer the outgoing packets generated from some servers and later release it to outside world on receiving a signal. This should be transparent to the servers running i.e should not require modification to the servers. This link https://docs.huihoo.com/doxygen/linux/kernel/3.7/sch__plug_8c_source.html seems to solve the problem but I'm unable to generate any small working example which can simulate this. The problem is how should I get hold of parameters passed to the functions such as `struct sk_buff *skb` , `struct nlattr *opt` etc.

As mentioned here in the I/O Buffering section (https://wiki.qemu.org/Features/MicroCheckpointing) **remus**(a fault tolerance approach to virtual machines) implementation of `qemu/kvm` also does this. Their code is somehwat complex to understand and we can't even open issues on the github page, so i'm looking for a working example which can do `plug`, `unplug` operations to buffer and release packets in the kernel queue `qdiscs`.

I already spent two weeks on it but couldn't do it. If it is possible to do in any other way which i'm not aware of, please post those solutions too.

Comment: @garethTheRed can you look into it?

Comment: here are the tool and pointer: https://manpages.debian.org/libnl-utils/nl-qdisc-add.8 + https://github.com/jfischoff/reuse-port-example#queuing-disciplines